# How to avoid writing ugly code while dealing with object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I find that when I write javascript I encounter a situation where I am forced to write ugly code. This is due to my inability to reconcile the following two criteria:

1) Define data using shorthand, e.g. `var data = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 3 ... } }`

2) Use a primitive operator to check for property existence

For example consider a function which returns the intersection of two `Object` instances' keys as an `Array` of the intersecting keys:

```
var intersection = function(obj1, obj2) {
    var result = [];
    for (var k in obj1) if (k in obj2) result.push(k);
    return result;
};
```

That code looks quite nice. But unfortunately, it doesn't always work as expected! This is due to the inconsistency between `for (x in y)`, and `if (x in y)`: Using `for (x in y)` will only iterate over "own" properties (properties which return true for `hasOwnProperty`), while `if (x in y)` while apply for "own" *and* "non-own" properties!

If I call `intersection` like so:

```
var obj1 = { toString: 'hahaha' };
var obj2 = {};
var intersectingKeys = intersection(obj1, obj2);
```

I will wind up with `intersectingKeys === [ 'toString' ];` Obviously this is not correct: an `intersection` operation involving an empty set (as `obj2` appears to be) must return an empty set. While `{}` is clearly intended to be "empty", our problem is that `('toString' in {}) === true`. This also applies to terms such as `'constructor'`, `'valueOf'`, as well as any new properties that are introduced to `Object.prototype` in the future.

In my opinion, **if a native operator can provide iteration over keys, a native operator should be able to verify whether a key will appear in an iteration.** It feels inconsistent and ugly, to me, to use a native operator for one, but a function call for the other. For that reason I dislike this fix:

```
var safeIntersection = function(obj1, obj2) {
    var result = [];
    for (var k in obj1) if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(k)) result.push(k);
    return result;
};
```

If `if (x in y)` must be used, I only see one other possible solution: Ensure that the parameters passed to `intersection` have no properties at all, apart from properties explicitly defined by our code. In other words, ensure that we only work with prototype-less objects:

```
var obj1 = Object.create(null, {
    toString: {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: 'hahaha'
    }
});
var obj2 = Object.create(null, {});
var intersectingKeys = intersection(obj1, obj2);
```

Note that this code uses `intersection`, not `safeIntersection`, and still works because `obj1` and `obj2` are prototype-less. But the problem is, now data definition is really, really clunky! Look at how much code it takes to define an object with a single "toString" property. This approach prevents us from using javascript's beautiful object-shorthand. Even if we write a utility function to encompass prototype-less object creation, the definition of nested objects is still incredibly clunky:

```
// Utility function for prototype-less object definition
var obj = function(props) {
    return Object.create(null, props.map(function(v) {
        return {
            writable: true,
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            value: v
        };
    }));
};

// Now defining `obj1` looks ok...
var obj1 = obj({ toString: 'hahaha' });

// But for large, nested object definitions it's sooper ugly:
var big = obj({
    a: 'a value',
    b: 'b value',
    moreProps: obj({
        wheee: 'yay',
        evenMoreProps: obj({
            prop: 'propMeUp'
            /* ... */
        })
        /* ... */
    })
});
```

Javascript's object-definition shorthand is a **huge** perk of the language, and throwing it away by being forced to wrap all `{ ... }` instances in a function call seems like a tremendous pity.

My ideal solution to this problem would involve converting the shorthand object constructor to produce prototype-less objects. Perhaps a global setting:

```
// Perhaps along with other global settings such as:
'use strict';
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

// We could also have: 
Object.shorthandIncludesPrototype = false;
```

Although even if this solutions were available it would break tons and tons of pre-existing libraries. :(

**How do I reconcile the following criteria???:**

**1) Write code that works**

**2) Use the primitive `in` operator to check for property existence**

**3) Define objects using typical shorthand**

Perhaps it's impossible to meet all these criteria simultaneously. In that case, what are some of the next-best approaches for keeping code clean in these cases?

Comment: Another way to approach this (which I would prefer) is to use a whitelist of legal properties for the API to query.  Then, you don't expose access to something accidentally just because it's on the object.  Just create a `Set` of the legal property names to query through the API and just check if the one that's being asked for is in that `Set` with one line of code before returning any values.

Comment: Do you know that you can create a prototype-less object with `Object.create(null)`?  I see that you do apparently know that.  Why not just use that?

Comment: My problem is with ugly code, not an inability to create prototype-less objects. I want to be able to do 2 things at the same time: 1) declare objects with shorthand, and 2) avoid have usages of `hasOwnProperty` all throughout my code.

Comment: You should be able to create one reusable function that reads a property off an object AND checks to see if it's a legal property to read.  Then rather than a direct property access, you just use that one function everywhere.  It should be no less ugly.  `getPropertySafe(obj, somePropName)`.

Comment: Still not as nice as `obj.somePropName`, but it's certainly possible there is no way to both use shorthand and avoid validation checks all over the place at the same time.

Comment: So, the language works the way the language works.  You can't change it.  Yes `in` works differently in two different contexts.  So, what do you want us to do about it?  Right now, this just seems like you know how the language works and you're frustrated by that.  You've made is a requirement that one use `in`, but you don't like how it works.  There's NOTHING we can do about that.  Get over it.  Find a practical solution to your problem and move on to something that's actually productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) already wrote, the question proposes constraints that are *fundamentally impossible* in the current versions of JavaScript. The best we can do is write some abstractions within the limitations of the language.

We've already looked at some possibilities, such as using a wrapper function (like `obj()` in the question). Because "universal support" is *not* a criterion in the question, I'll propose one solution using [ES6 Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). We can use the `has()` handler method of a `Proxy` to alter the behavior of the `in` operator so that it only considers *own* properties:

```js
Object.prototype.own = function () {
    return new Proxy(this, {
        has: function (target, propertyName) {
            return target.hasOwnProperty(propertyName);
        }
    });
};

document.writeln('toString' in {});
document.writeln('toString' in {}.own());
document.writeln('foo' in { foo: 1 });
document.writeln('foo' in { foo: 1 }.own());
```

This requires a modern browser (no IE; Edge OK) or [Node 6.4.0+](http://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-Proxy). Of course, adding members to the prototype of `Object` is a risky move. We can add additional handlers to the `Proxy` as needed, or rewrite the implementation for ES5 and below (but this requires significantly more code).

Compatibility concerns aside, this approach satisfies the requirements of the question: we can use object literals and the `in` operator, and the code is concise and readable. We just need to remember to call `own()` when we need it.

We can rewrite the `intersection()` method from the question using this convention:

```js
Object.prototype.own = function () {                                            
    return new Proxy(this, {                                                    
        has: function (target, propertyName) {                                  
            return target.hasOwnProperty(propertyName);                         
        }                                                                       
    });                                                                         
};

var intersection = function(obj1, obj2) {
    var result = [];
    for (var k in obj1.own()) if (k in obj2.own()) result.push(k);
    return result;
};

document.writeln(intersection({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get first the own properties of the first object with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and filter with [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) the second object's keys.

```js
function intersection(o1, o2) {
    return Object.keys(o1).filter({}.hasOwnProperty.bind(o2));
}

console.log(intersection({ a: 10, b: 20, e: 30 }, { a: 10, c: 20, d: 30 })); // ['a']
console.log(intersection({ toString: 'hahaha' }, {}));                       // []
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you've set out three incompatible requirements.  You say you have to use `in`.  You say objects have to be defined as `{}` so they will have a prototype.  But, you don't like the way `in` works.  And, you want code that uses those, but works differently than they are designed.  Those are your two choices.

**There's NO answer with those requirements.**  `in` works the way it does.  You can't change it.  We can't change it.  Yes, it works differently based on the context, but that's how it's implemented.  Deal with that by finding a practical solution to a real problem or write your own language that works the way you want the language to work.

FYI, for a real-world solution you may want to consider a `Map` object for storing your data and use `.get()`, `.has()` and `.set()` on it.  Simple, clear, works.

---

**Prior Answer BEFORE question was massively edited**

First off, you can just use `Object.create(null);` to create a prototype-less object.  So, the only properties it will have are the ones you put there.

I'd suggest that rather than accessing a property directly off the object, you just create one reusable function that checks to see if the property name is valid before returning it:

```
function sendValidProperty(req, res) {
    var propName = req.params.propertyName;
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dataObject, propName) {
        res.send(dataObject[propName]);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
}

router.get('/propertyOfObject/:propertyName', function(req, res) {
    sendValidProperty(req, res);
});
```

Or, you could encapsulate a smaller piece of it:

```
function getValidProperty(obj, propName) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dataObject, propName) ? obj[propName] : null;
}

router.get('/propertyOfObject/:propertyName', function(req, res) {
    let val = getValidProperty(dataObject, res.params.propertyName);
    if (val !== null) {
        res.send(val);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
});
```

In either case, you don't have to repeat the checking of a property.  That's in the common, shared function.  FYI, when you want to use object methods on a prototype-less object, you can use the form I show above: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dataObject, propName)` instead of `dataObject.hasOwnProperty(propName)`.

---

One of the main rules of server development is to NEVER trust the input you get from a request.  You always have to check it or sanitize it before using it.  This whole question kind of sounds like you're trying to avoid doing that.  You just can't shortcut checking input and have a fully reliable server.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer and I completely agree with your advice! Although I've edited my question to clarify exactly what I'm looking for - my original question may have been misleading, but I'm not focused on writing a safe server-side, I'm focused on a much more general issue.

Comment: @GershomMaes - It is widely frowned upon here to make such a significant edit to your question after answers have been provided that it COMPLETELY changes the meaning of your question.  It makes folks like me wonder why I bothered spending any time answering your original question.  FWIW, your current question mostly just seems like a rave about how you can't do what you want with less code.  It's hard to find an answerable question in there (particularly given that JS doesn't work the way you want it to).

Comment: @GershomMaes - I made one edit to the beginning of my question.  I plan on spending NO more time on your question as long as you maintain your current attitude because you've set out an impossible set of requirements and aren't apparently interested in discussing other solutions.  Thus, your question is mostly just a rant about how the language doesn't work the way you want.  And, please stop changing the meaning of questions with major edits after folks have already spent time commenting and answering.  If you want to go in a new direction some time in the future, then post a new question.

Comment: I don't believe the change is so significant. I made big changes to the text but the focus of the question is exactly the same - it's just clearer now. I wanted to remove any references to server-side development, even if I had mentioned that it was just an example, in order to avoid responses which just focused on server-side input handling. You say "objects have to be defined as {} so they will have a prototype", but is this necessarily true?

Comment: @GershomMaes - Well, I don't see any way to make `let x = {}` create an object that has no prototype.  Chrome won't let you mess with `Object.prototype` in the ways I tried.  And, if you did succeed, you'd break tons of other code that relies on built-in object methods.  So, again, I have no idea what kind of answer you're actually looking for here.  The language is designed to work a certain way.  And, in fact, the `Map` object was designed for a purpose similar to yours (keeping track of key/value pairs without any interference from built-in properties.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 extra solutions that are probably worth mentioning here:

## 1) Recursive `obj` function

As I mentioned in the question, having an `obj` method which creates an un-prototyped value from a regular `Object` defined via shorthand gets really ugly when it needs to be applied all throughout a nested shorthand structure - but this problem can be somewhat solved if the `obj` method is recursive, so that it only needs to be applied to the root `Object` and not explicitly to every inner child property:

```js
var obj = function(val) {
  if (val.constructor === Object) {
    var ret = Object.create(null);
    for (var k in val) ret[k] = obj(val[k]);
  } else if (val.constructor === Array) {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) ret.push(obj(val[i]));
  } else {
    var ret = val;
  }

  return ret;
};

var thing = obj({
  prop1: 'hello',
  prop2: 'hi',
  prop3: [
    { num: 1, val: 'lalala' },
    { num: 2, val: 'heehee' },
    { num: 3, val: 'hoho' },
  ],
  really: {
    deep: {
      property: {
        over: {
          here: { val: 'soooo deep' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

console.log('toString' in thing);
console.log('toString' in thing.prop3[1]);
console.log('toString' in thing.really.deep.property.over.here);
```

Now it's important that all shorthand objects are wrapped in `obj`.

## 2) Clear out `Object.prototype`

I've found that chrome and node (v0.12.0) will allow me to delete all properties from `Object.prototype`. The prototype can even be restored at any point in the future if these removed properties are kept in memory:

```
var savedPrototype = {};
var removePrototype = function() {
  savedPrototype = {};
  var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype);
  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    savedPrototype[props[i]] = Object.prototype[props[i]];
    delete Object.prototype[props[i]];
  }
};
var restorePrototype = function() {
  for (var k in savedPrototype) {
    Object.prototype[k] = savedPrototype[k];
  }
};

removePrototype();
var obj = { val: 'haha' };
console.log('toString' in obj); // false
restorePrototype();
console.log('toString' in obj); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be solved with some beautiful code.

### ES5

```
var intersect = function(obj1, obj2) {
  var keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  var keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  return keys1.filter(function(k) {
    return keys2.indexOf(k) !== -1;
  });
}
```

### ES6

```
let intersect = (obj1, obj2) => {
  let keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  let keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  return keys1.filter(k => keys2.includes(k));
}
```

This is the JavaScript way of solving such problems. It is way better, since you don't need to use any loop. The built-in methods like `filter()`, `indexOf()` or `includes()` would perform better than any loop.